# Ember View loses content

Tags: ember.js

I am working on a bit of code to show a D3 chart using Ember fixture data as the source for the data. The charts show up just fine on the first load of the page but if I move to a different route & then return to the first route (the one with the working chart) the chart simply disappears. So I guess my question is, **how do I get the chart to appear every time the route is visited?** Here is what my Route and View code looks like, will add more code if requested.

Updated with JS Bin: http://jsbin.com/ihapaz/2/edit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The route may not be getting any data when you return back to it. When using `linkTo` the `model` hooks are not fired. The `setupController` is called directly with the model that you pass to `linkTo`. However if the route depends on the model hook having fired to load it data then the view would be empty as it wouldn't have any data to render.

That's the only thing that comes to mind from the above code. Try posting a jsbin if this doesn't work.

### Edit: Post jsbin

After looking at your jsbin I realized my earlier answer was incorrect. In general it is true that `linkTo` skips the model hook, but only if dynamic segments are present. Your route has no dynamic segments. Hence the model hook will always be called, so the view/chart is getting data correctly.

The error is in your implementation of `render`. The purpose of the `render` method is to push strings of html onto the DOM. This isn't the appropriate place for custom DOM insertion. For that you need to put things on the `didInsertElement` method.

I made these changes, renaming `render` to `didInsertElement` and the corresponding `updateChart`. Here's the updated [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/ucutil/2/).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I believe you're correct about what is going on but I haven't had any luck fixing it, would you mind expanding a little on your answer? I've added a jsbin per your suggestion, should've done that right away.